# Values of new columns in view not showing

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, powershell

I have the following situation:
An existing list has been extended with several columns, all of the type **Readonly Field from other List**.
The Problem is, that the new columns do not show the values. If I open the item in edit mode and save it without changing anything, the values are shown for this item.

Since there are several hundred items in the list, I don't want to edit every single one. I tried to write a PowerShell script which iterates through all items and calls `$item.SystemUpdate($false)`, but that does not help.

Do you have any suggestions how I could get the values shown for all items?

Full script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $URL
$list = $web.Lists["listName"]
$view = $list.Views["viewName"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)

foreach($item in $items)
{
   $item.SystemUpdate($false)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my Problem, I had to get the value of the columns that must be shown from the referenced list and set them in the main list.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $URL
$list = $web.Lists["listName"]
$view = $list.Views["viewName"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
$referencedList = $web["referencedListName"]

foreach($item in $items)
{
   # get the id of the referenced item ($refId)
   $ref = $referencedList.GetItemById($refId)

   $refValue = $ref["referencedColumnName"]
   $item["columnName"] = $refValue

   $item.SystemUpdate($false)
}
```